# Calling Azure storage account REST APIs using Azure Data Factory Managed Identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

We are hoping to make a call to the "Blob Containers - Create" api endpoint i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blob-containers/create?view=rest-storagerp-2023-01-01&tabs=HTTP from the Azure data factory pipeline web activity.

While this typically works seamlessly with a dedicated Azure AD application registered with a secret, our aim is to execute the call using the Managed Identity of the Data Factory. The ADF's Managed Identity already holds the storage blob data contributor role assigned on the storage account.

Given that the REST endpoint necessitates the mandatory authorization header requiring a bearer token issued by Azure AD, we are currently encountering an issue in obtaining it for ADF's managed identity.

Any assistance on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, there is **no need** to generate access token separately while
> using managed identity authentication.

Initially, I added **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to ADF managed identity under storage account like this:

[image]

In your Azure data factory pipeline web activity, use below parameter values in **Settings** tab:

**URL :** https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storacc/blobServices/default/containers/sricontainer01?api-version=2023-01-01

**Method:**  PUT

**Body:** {"null": "null"}

**Authentication:**  System Assigned Managed Identity

**Resource:** https://management.azure.com

**Headers:** Content-Type : application/json

[image]

When I ran the pipeline, I got the response with **Succeeded** status as below:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where container created successfully in storage account like this:

[image]